# url for mp4 gives error, but mozila can download it. how can i download it with python instead

Tags: python-3.x, firefox, web-scraping

I am trying to make a script that downloads videos from a site. I see the video url but when I try to open it it gives `403 ERROR The request could not be satisfied. 
But in the video page when i choose view page info firefox can successfully download the video. In the description in the media tab there is a link location i am trying to access it but gives me the same error. 
I tried to download the video with pathlib but it saves it with the error. My question is how can i download this video?

Comment: Perhaps the data you are trying to fetch is controlled by EME, Encrypted Media Extensions.  That MAY account for your browser being able to display it but the W3C standards protocols no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python's `requests` module, you can create a browser-specific header to be included in the request. If you wanted to use Firefox for example:

```
mozhdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3'}
```

Then include it as an argument when you get the request

```
requests.get("https://www.youtube.com", headers = mozhdr)
```

Comment: That assumes that the problem is the user-agent string and not one of a host of other things.

Comment: Well the video is played by javascript and if i play the video and right click it i can save it. but when i try to open the link in the browser it gives this error. can i create this event of right click a video and open in new tab then use urllib to download it ?